# Integrating Google AppInvites to iOS App

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-app-invites

I'm interested in integrating new AppInvites by Google to my iOS app. There are some problems...I'm currently using googleplus-ios-sdk pod and it seems like I cannot have AppInvites pod with googleplus pod as they have some common classes (which results as error during linking of course).

I'm looking for solution how I can use both pod, or maybe there is another pod from Google that can do googleplus job.

Google site is not helping, I've found list of all pods published by Google:
https://developers.google.com/ios/cocoapods?hl=pl

but I don't see one for Google+.

Do you have any advice for this?

Comment: I am having same problem with Google's AppInvite for IOS. I did a new install from : pod try Google and selected AppInvites.xcodeproj. Then I configured the GoogleService-Info.plist, bundle ID and reverse client ID.
I can sign-in to my google account but when I select Invite Friends, it come out with an error "The operation couldn't be completed. (The caller does not have permission) The permission bug happens in their latest AppInvites version 1.0.2
I was using their older version 1.0.1 but did not see this bug.
I really hope they solve their AppInvites bug real soon.

Comment: Well I don't think it is the same bug. Maybe you should open another question?

Comment: @evang2015 - I'm able to run the app invites sample fine, you might want to try regenerating the GoogleService-Info.plist file from https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Comment: What are the errors you're seeing and what are you using the `googleplus-ios-sdk` for currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of your issue is that you're using v1 Sign-in (e.g. `GPP*` objects and the `GPPSignin` singleton) when you probably should be using [Google Sign-in 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios) (`GID*` objects and `GHI*` objects).

If you're using `GPPShare` then you may need to do more work to get it to work well alongside `GIDSignin`. It may be easier for you to use a link-based approach to sharing, e.g. pass a URL such as `https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://yourshareurl.com` to a web view or `open` call.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. But as far as I know and everythink there is no way to include google+ sdk and google sign in at the same time.